# Serilog sink is not sending log to DataDog

Tags: asp.net-mvc, serilog

I have setup DataDog on my local machine and trying to log from my asp.net mvc app. Here are the things I have done so far,

1. DataDog setup is done and logging is enabled in yaml file.
2. Added following piece of code in start of my app

Sub Application_Start()

```
 Dim config = New DatadogConfiguration(url:="intake.logs.datadoghq.com", port:=443, useSSL:=True, useTCP:=True)
    _log = New LoggerConfiguration() _
            .MinimumLevel.Debug() _
            .WriteTo.DatadogLogs("datadog-key", "csharp", "Application", "DESKTOP-R4FT16J", New String() {"ecom", "serilog"}, config) _
            .CreateLogger()
    Log.Logger = _log
    _log.Information("Serilog initiated for Ecom...")
```

3. Dont have appsettings.json or log.json file.
4. Nothing coming on dataDog yet.

Serilog Sink looks straightforward per documentation but something must be missing ?

Comment: Did you search for a troubleshooting checklist? It could be literally anything based on what you've provided. On the Serilog side, you can search for `serilog selflog`, but I suspect the variables and/or ways to diagnose issues in how the Datadog side connects will be more interesting

Comment: I tried looking everything but no luck. Tried all possible URLs/Port etc but no success.

Comment: Well, if datadog and/or the Datadog sink repo don't have a troubleshooting guide, they should have one... I'd definitely look at the serilog selflog too and/or read the datadog sink repo to see what it does